# How do I unblock a Background Task (Facebook)?

Tags: 8.0, background-tasks

I have some background tasks that are blocked (I never blocked them) and I can't unblock them.

I'm trying to unblock Facebook, so I made sure **Turn background tasks back on for this app the next time I open it** was checked and launched the app, but it's still blocked.

[image: bg tasks][image: bg tasks details]

How do I unblock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook app from Microsoft uses Push notifications and live tiles, but not background tasks. If it did, it would be enabled by default, or at least pop-up an option for you to decide. Since this app never did, and never will use the Background Tasks feature, the tickbox in your screenshot won't make a difference.

Comment: I think Facebook does use background tasks if you choose it as a lock screen app.

Comment: I don't have ''background tasks'' at my settings section :( my phone is lumia 610